# Downloaded ios simulator doesn't appear at xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I downloaded ios 10.3.1 version in xcode 9.4

[image]

But I only can select the ios 11 version I already have.

[image]

I rebooted OS and restarted Xcode already. I also can see ios 10 simulator when I select "add additional simulators"

[image]

There are ios10, 11 simulator both of them. I don't know how to use ios 10 simulators in xcode that I already downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

> **Change `Deployment Target` from iOS 11.x to iOS 10.x**

[image]

(Xcode shows simulator in a device list with iOS version >= Deployment Target.)

Comment: @MJJung - You can accept this answer, if it helped you. :) See here: [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376995)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If I understand your problem correctly, changing Deployment target should help. It can be found in General section of settings shown when you first launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

To use that the project compatibility should be lesser. That means the **Deployment target** in your app should be from iOS 10.

Go to **project target settings**. **Deployment target** --> **10.x**

Comment: Accept this answer @MJJung, if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers didn't help me, I'll describe my solution.

`The deployment target doesn't always solve the problem, as well as creating a new scheme. The simulators don't appear automatically.`

1. Press **Add Additional Simulators**
   [image]
2. Choose **Simulators tab**
   [image]
3. **Create a new device simulator**. Choose `Device Type` and `OS Version` whichever available
   [image]
4. Your simulator should appear
   [image]